# Order and sign of a cycle

Tags: group-theory, permutation-cycles

I would usually show workings or attempts of a method when posting a question here, but for this I am completely lost. I don't believe it to be a very hard question but it is as follows:

Determine the order and the sign of $(5\,6\,7\,8\,9)(3\,4\,5\,6)(2\,3\,4)(1\,2)$ in $S_9$.

(Each number is separate i.e. the first is 5,6,7,8 and 9 but I wasn't sure of how to create a horizontal space).

I appreciate any help offered, even if it is just a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Write your element of $S_9$ as the product of disjoint cycles. For instance, one of those cycles will be $(1\ \ 4\ \ 2)$.

Comment: Thanks! Would the product of disjoint cycles be given by (1 4 2)(3 6)(5 7 8 9) by any chance?

Comment: That is correct!